# How to implement camera in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

My app always crashes when I press the camera button. I am trying to get the camera to appear on my screen when I press the camera button.

```
@IBAction func ACPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()

    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .camera

    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

private func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String :AnyObject] ){        
    camera.image = info [UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage; dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: When you app crashes are you getting a stack trace or other error messages that you can add to the question by editing it?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a simulator issue.  If you want to add code to handle this case, you can do the following:

```
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

By wrapping it in "isSourceTypeAvailable", it will avoid the crash.  You can add an else statement in there and display an alert message notifying of the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use simulator to test the camera. Use real device.
Another way you will see the exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Source type 1 not available'

```
class ViewController:UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    private var imagePicker    : UIImagePickerController!
    private var photo: UIImage?

    @IBAction func ACPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        imagePicker            = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate   = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        photo = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

    }
}
```

> Don't forget to set "Privacy - Camera Usage Description" in your
>   Info.plist

I don't know why my answer is downvoted but try this code on the real device and you will see that the code works perfect!

Comment: two errors: `Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type '(UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate)?'`and `photo = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage`... maybe that was the issue?